# Can we create single DevOps CI/CD pipeline for both application and database deployment to Azure?

Tags: azure-pipelines, devops, cicd

I am using ADO.net in my MVC core project so SQL database has tables, procedures and functions etc. In most of the time, with application code, we also have database artefacts changes and need to deploy in sync. I need to have a single pipeline where I can define the sequencing of the deployment e.g. database artefacts should be deployed first and then application. Can we do this?
If yes then how to do this, will be helpful if you provide any tutorial or video link.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to have a single pipeline where I can define the sequencing of the deployment e.g. database artefacts should be deployed first and then application. Can we do this?

To define the sequencing of the deployment, you can define the running sequence of deploying database and application.

**Build Classic Pipeline:**

You could define the **Dependencies** in `Agent Job -> Dependencies`.

[image]

**Build YAML Pipeline:**

You can use the **dependsOn** Parameter .

```
stages:
- stage: BuildWin
  displayName: Build for Windows
- stage: BuildMac
  displayName: Build for Mac
  dependsOn: BuildWin
```

**Release Pipeline：**

You could  define the execution order of stages.

[image]

For more detailed info, you could refer to the doc: [YAML Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#stage), [Add stages, dependencies, & conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) , [Specify jobs in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic)